# Error verifying scanner input contains two words with one space

Tags: java, string, loops, validation, java.util.scanner

Trying to verify the user just enters psuedo code: word1 space word2. This seems like it should be simple logic, if string doesn't equal word1 space word2, ask again. I've built a version with if/else logic that catches it properly, it just doesn't ask again. So i've tried to modify to use the do while loop.

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a two word phrase with one space.");
        String phrase = sc.nextLine();
        phrase = phrase.trim();
        int i1 = phrase.indexOf(" ");
        int i2 = phrase.indexOf(" ", i1 +1);
            do{
              System.out.println("Enter a two word phrase with one space, Try Again!");
              phrase = sc.nextLine();
            }while(i2 != -1);
            System.out.println("Correct");
        }
```

The result of this code is that it just takes the input twice and ends with correct regardless of what is enters.

Comment: i2 in while body never updates and always stays the same it was in 3rd line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a two word phrase with one space.");
    String phrase = sc.nextLine();
    phrase = phrase.trim();
    int i1 = phrase.indexOf(" ");
    int i2 = phrase.indexOf(" ", i1);
    while (i2 == -1) {
        System.out.println("Enter a two word phrase with one space, Try Again!");
        phrase = sc.nextLine();
        i1 = phrase.indexOf(" ");
        i2 = phrase.indexOf(" ", i1);
    }
    System.out.println("Correct");
```

Comment: That works great. I have one other test case, it needs to also ask the user to try again if they enter three words with two spaces. I tried to add `int i3 = phrase.indexOf(" ", i2 + 1);` outside the while loop and `i3 = phrase.indexOf(" ", i2 + 1);' inside, but it still returns correct if i enter word1 space word2 space word3.

Comment: You can create a String array wich contains the splittet String of the input String(phrase).: With one Space the Array length would be 2. Whith 2 Spaces it would be three.

Comment: String[] controller = phrase.split(" ");
        System.out.println(controller.length);

Comment: You split your phrase at the Spaces (" ")

Answer (score 0):

In your do-while loop, the value `i2` is never updated.

```java
int i1 = phrase.indexOf(" ");
int i2 = phrase.indexOf(" ", i1 +1);
```

is outside your while loop, so i2 is never updated and thus the while loop cannot and will not end.

Therefore, this part belongs in the loop:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String phrase;
int idx;

do {
  System.out.println("Enter a two word phrase with one space!");
  phrase = sc.nextLine().trim();

  int spaceIdx = phrase.indexOf(" ");
  idx = phrase.indexOf(" ", spaceIdx + 1);
} while(idx != -1);

System.out.println("Correct");
```